# catalogued vs uncatalogued IBM database

Tags: database, db2

In plain English, why does this differentiation even exist: catalogued vs uncatalogued IBM databases? especially that IBM states that open creation a database is catalogued.
When should I catalogue a database and when should I uncatalogue it?

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of a catalogue (as implemented in DB2 linux/unix/windows) for nodes and databases are useful for applications that use CLI (call level interface) to access DB2 databases and servers. This includes scripts that use the CLP (command line processor) for ksh/bash/cmd.exe etc.

If you are using a jdbc Type-4 driver, these concepts are not useful. If you are using a jdbc Type-2 driver, the catalogue remains relevant.

These concepts provide a method for indirect access to servers or databases, with the goal of avoiding changes to apps just to reference a different copy of a database.

Think of a node directory as a store of pointers to database-servers.   Think of a database-directory as a store of pointers to databases on nodes, and those nodes can be local to the current DB2-instance, or the nodes can reference other DB2-instances which themselves can be on the same hostname or on remote hostnames.   The idea is that you can change the pointers (i.e. the database-aliases , or the nodes) to reference different objects without needing to change the application connection-string. The catalog action adds items (alias to database, or database, or node), uncatalog removes items - but does not affect the physical-database(s).

DB2 implements the catalogue (the node directory, and the database-directory) as local files on the DB2-client, or the local DB2-client that exists on a DB2-server.

Catalogues are useful in an environment where you have many categories of dev and test. You can alias databases to point to any environment, which has benefits for data-exchange or comparison of DDL or content - and the relevant scripts or code does not need to change or reconfigure (unless credentials change)

Answer (score 0):

A database is cataloged on the LOCAL machine once created but if you need to access it from a remote system you need to catalog it there as the remote machine does not recognize the creation of the database - obviously.
Besoides the catalog database you will also need a catalog node which identifies the remote system.

Another point is that if you uninstall Db2 on your local machine after you have created a database the database will stay so you could manually catalog it after you reinstalled Db2 (i.e. in anoher version).

Comment: is it like cataloged = saved on local machine. Uncataloged = saved somewhere else?

Comment: no - it is used to undo a catalog command if you misspelled something or you moved your database to another machine etc.